# Why batch file skip command in FORFILES?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, forfiles

Wanna ask, below is my code...

```
time /t > c:\logs.txt
date /t >> c:\logs.txt

pushd \\172.31.100.101\dir1\dir2

set sour2ndP=%CD%\Recon1
set dest2ndP=%CD%\Recon2

set sour2ndC=%CD%\Recon3
set dest2ndC=%CD%\Recon4

set sour3rd=%CD%\Recon5
set dest3rd=%CD%\Recon6

set sour4th=%CD%\Recon7
set dest4th=%CD%\Recon8

set sour5th=%CD%\Recon9
set dest5th=%CD%\Recon10

FORFILES /p %sour2ndP% /M *.* /C "cmd /c xcopy /y /z /f @file %dest2ndP% >> c:\logs.txt" /D +0
FORFILES /p %sour2ndC% /M *.* /C "cmd /c xcopy /y /z /f @file %dest2ndC% >> c:\logs.txt" /D +0
FORFILES /p %sour3rd% /M *.* /C "cmd /c xcopy /y /z /f @file %dest3rd% >> c:\logs.txt" /D +0
FORFILES /p %sour4th% /M *.* /C "cmd /c xcopy /y /z /f @file %dest4th% >> c:\logs.txt" /D +0
FORFILES /p %sour5th% /M *.* /C "cmd /c xcopy /y /z /f @file %dest5th% >> c:\logs.txt" /D +0

popd
```

And below is the logs.txt

```
04:25 AM
Tue 12/09/2023 
Z:\Recon3\bbb.dat -> Z:\Recon4\bbb.dat
1 File(s) copied
Z:\Recon5\ccc.dat -> Z:\Recon6\ccc.dat
1 File(s) copied
Z:\Recon7\ddd.dat -> Z:\Recon8\ddd.dat
1 File(s) copied
Z:\Recon9\eee.dat -> Z:\Recon10\eee.dat
1 File(s) copied
```

My question is why the batch script skip '\recon1 to \recon2' line ?
If I execute manually, it'll not skip
But if using task scheduler, '\rcon1 to \recon2' line is always skip
Thx in advance

Answer (score -2):

```
pushd \\172.31.100.101\dir1\dir2&timeout /T 1 >nul
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if you actually explained why the `timeout` is needed instead of just having a code-only answer. On a related note, chaining two commands together with an `&` is almost universally a bad idea because it decreases readability and makes debugging significantly more difficult.

Comment: There is no execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` needed after `cmd.exe` finished the execution of its internal command __PUSHD__. That code makes absolutely no sense and does not answer the question. The specified code makes never sense anywhere.

Comment: I've added &timeout /T 1 >nul.
But it's still not working. It's still skip \recon1 to \recon2' line